# What algorithm does Devise use for implementing Remember Me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, security, devise, remember-me

What algorithm/method does Devise use for implementing Remember Me?

What tokens does it create, what values do those tokens have, what values does it store in the database, how and when those values change?

Basically I am looking for a detailed clarification and account of how Devise handles Remember Me?

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding it stores your credentials into the browser's cache & when you log in next time it can identify you easily